# Are there any good documents for mongo_mapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

After some searches, I found the documentation of mongo_mapper is poor.

There is only a short readme on GitHub, only one article in http://mongomapper.com, and just a list of classes in the RDoc.

I know there is a good screencast at http://railscast.com, but I want some more good documents about how to using mongo_mapper.

Are there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of MongoMapper, John Nunemaker, [writes about it quite a lot on his blog](http://railstips.org/blog/labels/mongomapper/).

Answer (score 1):

I've used Mongoid, and been pretty happy with the documentation and community support. If you are just researching, you may check it out before deciging.